# Rails: Browsers re-validate assets even with assets digest enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have been trying to get rid of the re-validation requests made by browsers for our Rails app. I turned on asset digests:

```
      config.assets.digest = true
```

and was hoping that the 304's go away. but they don't (the assets are md5'ed):

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4379dca12de4846777a274a301167a41.css" for 192.168.56.1 at Sun Mar 03 00:34:22 +0100 2013
[INFO  pid: 3967: 13-03-03 00:34:22 ] Served asset /bootstrap/bootstrap-4379dca12de4846777a274a301167a41.css - 304 Not Modified (5ms)
```

For reference - this is the raw html in the page:

```
  <link href="/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4379dca12de4846777a274a301167a41.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I checked the cache headers using curl - and they look good:

```
< Content-Type: text/css
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 200
< X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11
< ETag: "4379dca12de4846777a274a301167a41"
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
< Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 08:03:21 GMT
< X-Rack-Cache: miss, store
< X-Content-Digest: 97d1f611b557f55fa917899bca0ef9b674d65a6a
< X-Runtime: 0.023510
< Date: Sat, 02 Mar 2013 23:43:37 GMT
< Content-Length: 141338
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
< Age: 0
< Server: nginx/1.0.10 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
```

if I load this css URL straight from the browser - then the browser does seem to cache it. (Refresh doesn't generate a GET on the rails log). However when I load my application page - it always issues a re-validate resulting in 304.

I have toyed around with these settings (true/false, present/absent) (**pretty much tried all combinations**) (and always removing tmp/cache just to play it safe):

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=30758400"
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

but nothing has helped. I have read somewhere that the 'Etag' header is the issue - but I can't figure out how to turn off the Etag header (no matter what i do - the etag header is always returned). (And I can't figure out why the official recipe doesn't just work).

This is in development mode - but i have changed the config settings as indicated above. No precompilation.

Any help on how to turn off the re-validations greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Rails probably isn't adding those headers…nginx is. Check out the Rails guides section on this (scroll down to 4.1.1):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Specifically the "For nginx" portion:

```
location ~ ^/assets/ {
  expires 1y;
  add_header Cache-Control public;

  add_header ETag "";
  break;
}
```